# C expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’

Tags: c

The point of the exercise (for university) is to create a function that calculates the perimeter of a triangle once given the coordinates of its 3 corners.
I am a beginner at C and after some work I have managed to create a code that more or less does its intended job, however i have stumbled upon the following error:

trperim.c:25:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
trperim.c:31:58: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
 double trperim(double r1[2], double r2[2], double r3[2]);{

I have been unable to solve this, and so I turn to this community.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double trperim(double r1[2], double r2[2], double r3[2]);
double norm(double r[2]); 

main()
{
double r1[2], r2[2], r3[2];
printf("Ingrese las coordenadas del primer vertice en x:");
scanf("%lf",&r1[0]);
printf("Ingrese las coordenadas del primer vertice en y:");
scanf("%lf",&r1[1]);
printf("Ingrese las coordenadas del segundo vertice en x:");
scanf("%lf",&r2[0]);
printf("Ingrese las coordenadas del segundo vertice en y:");
scanf("%lf",&r2[1]);
printf("Ingrese las coordenadas del tercer vertice en x:");
scanf("%lf",&r3[0]);
printf("Ingrese las coordenadas del tercer vertice en y:");
scanf("%lf",&r3[1]);
printf("El perimetro del triangulo es %f\n", trperim(r1,r2,r3));
}

double norm(double r[2]);
{
double modulo, r[2];
modulo=sqrt(pow(r[0],2)+pow(r[1],2));
return modulo;
}

double trperim(double r1[2], double r2[2], double r3[2]);{
double nr1, nr2, nr3, p;
nr1=norm(r1-r2);
nr2=norm(r2-r3);
nr3=norm(r3-r1);
p=nr1+nr2+nr3;
return p;
}
```

Comment: Hint: check line number 25.

Comment: Remove the semi-colons `;` after function implementations.

Comment: This line is also suspect `double modulo, r[2];` - `r` is an argument as well!

Comment: Why use pow(x,2) when x*x avoids the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;`s after `....(double r[2])` and `...double r3[2])`from the function definitions.

In your code

```
 double norm(double r[2]);
 ...
 double trperim(double r1[2], double r2[2], double r3[2]);{
```

should be

```
 double norm(double r[2])
 ....
 double trperim(double r1[2], double r2[2], double r3[2]) {
```

That said, rename the local variable `r` in `norm()` as you already have `r` as the function parameter.